# ember.js user params not getting passed to model

Tags: ember.js

I have a 'watch' template that should show info about a game and the teams. I also wanted to display the currently logged in user's details on the page.

However when I add `('user', params.id)` I get the error `params is not defined ReferenceError:`

routes/watch.js

```
App.WatchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      game: this.store.find('game'),
      team: this.store.find('team'),
      user:  this.store.find('user', params.id)
    })
  }
});
```

models/user.js

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  uid: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  profileImage: DS.attr('string'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('number')
});
```

models/game.js

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
  gameName: DS.attr('string'),
  teams: DS.hasMany('team'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('number')
});
```

models/team.js

```
App.Team = DS.Model.extend({
  teamName: DS.attr('string'),
  game: DS.belongsTO('game'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('number')
})
```

router.js

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('login');
  this.resource('logout');
  this.resource('signup', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('home', { path: '/:id' });
  this.resource('watch', { path: '/watch/:id' });
  this.resource('games');
  this.resource('game', {path: 'teams/:id'});      
  this.resource('teams');
  this.resource('team', {path: 'teams/:id'});
});
```

Comment: params are passed into the model hook. You have used ''model: function() {', i think by making it 'model: function(params) {' it should work

Comment: @blessenm I have now added that and getting the error:
 `Error while processing route: watch Assertion Failed: You may not pass "undefined" as id to the store's find method`

Comment: Assuming you're using the link-to helper, are you giving it a value for the id? Check this out from the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem. I had not included the watch in the application.js with `this.get('user')`